# Python: subprocess.stdin.write is not working properly

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm new to python but I can code and debug a bit. The following problem has been on my head for the past couple of days and looking out for an answer. Any help is much appreciated.
Task: I wanted to do an interactive telnet (I know there is an telnet library, but we are not using it for various reasons). 
For this purpose, I use a subprocess.popen

```
p = subprocess.Popen(telnet_command,
                         stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout = outputfileobj,
                         stderr = errorfileobj)
```

I do a poll() to see if the server has got connected to the session. Once I verified, I proceed to write to the stdin for interactive communication.

```
inputTxt = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: ' + hostheader + '\n\n'
p.stdin.write(inputTxt)
p.stdin.flush()
```

Here is where the problem has occurred. I get the http response (or atleast output) for 5/6 times but 1/6 time, I do not get a output and the subprocess gets terminated - which is not possible.

I ran a system trace for the failure case and please find below the same.

```
16129 write(7, "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.google."..., 37) = 37
16129 gettimeofday({1310538497, 134474}, NULL) = 0
16129 futex(0x81993a8, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)   = 0
16129 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56, ...}) = 0
16129 fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=520689, ...}) = 0
16129 _llseek(4, 520689, [520689], SEEK_SET) = 0
16129 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56, ...}) = 0
16129 write(4, "2011-07-13 06:28:17,134 : pconns"..., 170) = 170
16129 futex(0x81d3b30, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)   = 0
16129 waitpid(16198, 0xffa945e8, WNOHANG) = 0
16129 gettimeofday({1310538497, 135160}, NULL) = 0
16129 fstat64(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81, ...}) = 0
16129 fstat64(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81, ...}) = 0
16129 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf74b9000
16129 _llseek(6, 0, [0], SEEK_SET)      = 0
16129 fstat64(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81, ...}) = 0
16129 _llseek(6, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)      = 0
16129 read(6, "Trying 74.125.236.48...\nConnecte"..., 4096) = 81
16129 read(6, "", 4096)                 = 0
16129 close(6)                          = 0
16129 munmap(0xf74b9000, 4096)          = 0
16129 gettimeofday({1310538497, 135778}, NULL) = 0
16129 futex(0x81993a8, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)   = 0
16198 <... select resumed> )            = 1 (in [0])
16198 read(0, "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.google."..., 8191) = 37
16129 stat64("/etc/localtime",  <unfinished ...>
16198 ioctl(1, TCFLSH, 0)               = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
16129 <... stat64 resumed> {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56, ...}) = 0
16198 select(4, [0 3], [3], [3], {0, 0}) = 1 (out [3], left {0, 0})
16129 fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=520859, ...}) = 0
16198 send(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHos\377\363\377\375\6", 24, 0 <unfinished ...>
16129 _llseek(4, 520859,  <unfinished ...>
16198 <... send resumed> )              = 24
16198 select(4, [0 3], [3], [3], {0, 0} <unfinished ...>
16129 <... _llseek resumed> [520859], SEEK_SET) = 0
16198 <... select resumed> )            = 1 (out [3], left {0, 0})
16198 send(3, ": www.google.com\r\n\r\n", 20, 0 <unfinished ...>
16129 stat64("/etc/localtime",  <unfinished ...>
16198 <... send resumed> )              = 20
```

If you closely look at the line **16198 send(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHos\377\363\377\375\6", 24, 0**  in the trace, the string "Hos**t**" is replaced by some "Hos**\377\363\377\375\6**". I'm not sure why this occurs once in a while and also this closes the telnet connection I established. Please let me know if you need more data.

Comment: Why are you making HTTP request to a telnet server?, or you are just testing connecting to google.com at 80?

Comment: We are trying to check if a server support persistant connections(can post multiple requests after getting connected).

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to use the `communicate()` method to send data to the subprocess instead of using stdin, as the latter is discouraged by [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> Warning: Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Try this:

```
p.communicate(input='GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: ' + hostheader + '\n\n')
```

Comment: Yes, I can try it but the problem is its not one command I wanted to execute in that opened process. Instead, I need to execute many in that session. Thats the first reason I decided to use poll() and stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Though **communicate** is better, if you really have to use **stdin.write** you can make the calls non-blocking using:

`fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)`

for better understanding read this:

[io non blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to interact, I don't use communicate, but put the text into a pipe ahead of time.
I've not found a more pythonic "text_to_stream" yet.

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess


def text_to_stream(text):
    p = os.pipe()
    os.write(p[1], text.encode('utf-8'))
    os.close(p[1])
    return os.fdopen(p[0], "r")


def run(cmd, stdin_text=None):
    stdin = text_to_stream(stdin_text) if stdin_text else sys.stdin
    result = subprocess.run(
        cmd, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, stdin=stdin)
    result.check_returncode()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for those who actually want to solve the problem as written--when you need interactive output (meaning me five minutes ago)--specifically when `communicate()` is **not** the correct answer because you need to provide multiple chunks of input.

In the below program, I set up the child's stdout to be non-blocking (might be necessary for stderr as well, depending on use case) to allow me to read.  Another option could be to see if the underlying fd is readable with `select` or friends.

I then write to the child's stdin; and do an explicit flush to make sure it goes out, then check to see if anything came back.  In this specific example, the first read returns None, and then each read after that return's the previous cycle's (transformed) write data.

Obviously making the child not buffer its output unto infinity is left as an exercise for the reader.  I hacked it for this toy example by using the `unbuffer` program, but that is not appropriate for all examples.  However, beware of deadlock if you are sending a lot of data; you might have to read partial results before you write the entire buffer (this is where setting sp.stdin to non-blocking might be required, or generally more sophisticated I/O handling).

When the child terminates, the `flush()` got a `BrokenPipeError` exception (in my example, another possibility would be getting that in the `write()`.

While it is not appropriate for my use case, if you are doing a true interactive application where you need to respond to specific things the child does, using the pexpect module is probably the correct answer.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
import fcntl

sp = subprocess.Popen(["timeout", "2", "unbuffer", "-p", "tr", ".", "-"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fl = fcntl.fcntl(sp.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sp.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
while True:
    val = str(time.time()) + "\n"
    x = sp.stdin.write(val.encode("utf-8"))
    sp.stdin.flush()
    y = sp.stdout.read(1024)
    print(f"Wrote {x} bytes of {val[:-1]}, got {y}")
    time.sleep(0.4)
```